# Can iOS launch images be animated GIFs?

Tags: ios, ios7, animated-gif

Can iOS launch images be animated GIFs? If so will they play animated during launch? Just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Launch images are required to be PNG images, preferably non-interlaced.

Source: [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ExpectedAppBehaviors/ExpectedAppBehaviors.html)

Answer (score 0):

Launch images can't be animated gifs, as Mike Fay mentioned.

What you can do is display a UIImageView right after launch, and use the animated images feature of UIImageView to animate through a sequence of PNGs. See the [UIImageView documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), particularly the properties/methods listed under Animating Images.